# vb.net use WebBrowser and navigate through pages using the pages buttons

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

In vb.net I'm successfully getting logged into a secure website using this method.

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "me@email.com")
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "my_pw")
webBrowswer.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

The secure site returns an HTML page which is displayed properly in the webBrowser control and control is passed back to the user.

The user clicks a button on the form (part of the form, above the browser window) which causes the application to perform some commands based on information on that page.

This webpage has controls at the bottom of the page which allow a user to retrieve another page from the site.  The controls are a page number and a submit button.

Instead of asking a user to locate these form controls and go from page to page, I would like to have the application do this for him.

The problem is that the new page (page 2 for example) doesn't actually load in the webBrowser window.  So, the webBrowser.document doesn't change.

An infinite loop ensues.  However, if I allow the program to return control back to the user and force him to move to the next page, the webBrowser.document IS reloaded with the new page's contents

So, what is different from clicking these navigation ("next page") controls manually vs. programmatically?

```
dim sUrl as string = "https://www.example.com/with_parameters"
webBrowser.Navigate(sUrl)
sNewPage = webBrowser.DocumentText
```

Here is the code used to move to the next page:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("gotopage").Focus()
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("gotopage").SetAttribute("Value", iNextPage)
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("gotopage-button).InvokeMember("click")
sNewPage = webBrowser.DocumentText
```

This webBrowser.DocumentText is NOT loaded with the contents of the new page.
What could I do to force this to contain the new page's content?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI there's the [**`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) which is a reliable way of knowing when the page has loaded, rather than inserting a `Sleep()`.

Comment: thanks. i'll get that in there too. any thoughts on the question?

Comment: It's a bit hard understanding what exactly you want to use the `sNewPage` variable for, and without knowing the page it is also hard to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: The variable sNewPage just holds the entire HTML of the page being sent from the website.  It's easily populated at the first page load.  I'm just having difficulty seeing how to access the html page that results from "clicking" (virtually) the "Next Page" button.

Comment: Use the `DocumentCompleted` event for that. It is raised every time a page has finished loading.

Comment: Your way of explaining what is happening is a bit hard to understand. While your English has few grammatical issues, it fails to convey meaning clearly.  Hopefully you or someone from the community can edit your post to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander for letting me know that my question was unclear.  I've attempted to clean it up and be more specific.  Let's see if that helps!

Comment: WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted fires about 8 times as this page loads.  I've checked the value of .document each time and even after sleeping for 30 seconds following the final "completed" - still not updated.  BUT, if I do other tasks and some messagebox.show()'s, the .document will eventually populate with the desired page.